# How stretch curly brace on multi-line text?

Tags: formatting

What's the cell option (or other technique) to use to stretch the curly brace that one typically uses in traditional math to group several displayed equations? Like this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And is there any better way of getting the vertical alignments of the equations that simply inserting a 3-column table?

Comment: You could try using Piecewise (ESC pw ESC).  It doesn't look exactly the same though.

Comment: I know there *is* some such option -- something to do with "span" I think -- but I cannot find it now in Option Inspector. I even recall that somebody at WRI wrote to MathGroup about this several years ago.

Comment: I found the option: `SpanMaxSize`. If you change its value from the default `Automatic` to `Infinity`, then the opening brace will be stretched so as to enclose all the rows of the table.

Comment: @murray Your approach works very well when used in a `Style` wrapper for a `FormBox` containing the brace. This should be an answer.

Comment: @Jens: I didn't actually us a `Style` wrapper for a `FormBox` (I hate programming using boxes!) Rather, I used the option for the entire cell. For my purposes that sufficed, although I can envision others where it would be too crude an approach.

Comment: @murray In any case, your comment gave me the idea for my answer. And probably also for Mr. Wizard's answer. I just wanted to wait and see if you'd post something yourself...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is one of my personal examples:

[image]

How I did it:

- Ctrl 9 (inline cell); doesn't work on/as the first case/letter of a Text cell (needs at leas a space)
- esc pw esc
- copy paste inside the pw element the output of something like `Grid[{{a}, {b}, {c}}, Alignment -> Left]`
- substitute the content a, b, c with your content

Then you can reuse it... (I have an entire book written with these structures)

Your example, with the same technique:

[image]

You can obviously tweak it a lot with `Spacings`, `ItemSize`, `Style`, etc

And you can even go to the extreme of:

- Ctrl 9
- esc pw esc
- write inside the pw element `Grid[{{HoldForm[x-1=t]},{HoldForm[y=1-t^2]}},Alignment->"="]`
- select the `Grid[...]`, and choose `evaluate in place` (from the context menu)

[image]

...and editing it holds the alignment specification to the `"="` sign!

And for the slightly extra extension of the brackets:

[image]

It is also possible to simulate an align to different characters, although the only way I found is a little messier. There are invisible characters available in Mathematica. Be careful because they are... well... invisible. This means that you can mess things if they end up in the middle of computations... I'm going to demonstrate the technique with the `esc am esc` (aka `\[AlignmentMarker]`).

Another problem with this technique is that, since there is an invisible thing in the middle of the expression, the parser complains about it. So, I entered everything as strings (there's probably a better way of avoiding it). But, entering everything as string, brakes special characters formating during evaluation in place... But everything ends up working after editing it. Here is a way of doing:

- Ctrl 9
- esc pw esc
- write inside the pw element `Column[{Null,Grid[{{"test\[AlignmentMarker]=b"},{"bigger test\[AlignmentMarker]>b"}},Alignment->"\[AlignmentMarker]"],Null},ItemSize->{Automatic,{0.1,{02.},0.1}}]`
- select the `Column[...]`, and choose `evaluate in place` (from the context menu)

[image]

- edit to your needs (including the erasing of the `"`'s, but, while editing, don't erase your markers!)

[image]

Comment: I selected this as the answer because it seems to "kill two birds with one stone": to extend the brace and to align things on the equal sign. It even works to align on the equal sign when you have merely a series of equalities broken across lines (with nothing preceding the = on succeeding lines).


However, it will *not* work if you have inequalities as well as  qualities on the several lines; apparently `Alignment` won't let you specify more than a single character on which to align in a `Grid`. (I would love to be proved wrong here.)

Comment: @murray I just added a way of aligning to different characters (not exactly true, but I think it gives what you want)

Comment: "Ctrl 9 (inline cell); doesn't work on/as the first case/letter of a Text cell (needs at least a space)" Which version were you using? This seems to be a fixed bug. I tested in _v8.0.4_, _v9.0.1_, _v12.3.1_, win 10, space is not needed before pressing Ctrl+9.

Answer (score 17):

I would use a formatting function like this:

```
Format[bracket[obj_]] :=
  Style[DisplayForm @ RowBox[{"{", obj}], SpanMaxSize -> Infinity]
```

Or with `MakeBoxes`, which [may be preferable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4119830/618728):

```
MakeBoxes[bracket[obj_], fmt_] :=
  StyleBox[RowBox[{"{", obj ~ToBoxes~ fmt}], SpanMaxSize -> Infinity]
```

(You don't need both definitions at the same time.)

Then it will left-bracket whatever expression you give it:

```
Grid[Binomial ~Array~ {5, 5}] // bracket
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
{"one", "two", "three"} // Column // bracket
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[Sinc[x], {x, 0, 10}] // bracket
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

As a separate answer to the second part of your question you can use the `Alignment` option.
This works with both Strings and held expressions:

```
Column[{"x = 1+t", "two = 1-t^2", "three = 1+t^3"}, Alignment -> "="]

Column[
 HoldForm /@ Unevaluated@{x = 1 + t, two = 1 - t^2, three = 1 + t^3}, 
 Alignment -> "="
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Combined with `bracket`:

```
% // bracket
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Nice. Is it possible, perhaps by some minor tweak or use of an alignment marker, to align the equal sign of equations of varying lengths?

Comment: @David I guess I should add something about that to my answer, but I saw it as a side matter.

Comment: This answer, like some others, requires what seems to be an inordinate amount of coding for what ought to be a simple, straightforward text-entry issue about very basic mathematical typesetting. (Makes one wonder how much the Mathematical front-end designers really know about mathematical typesetting.)

Comment: Also, the alignment part of this answer won't handle the situation where you have some equalities and some inequalities. Any decent mathematical typesetting ought to allow alignment on characters that vary from one line to the next!

Comment: @murray Just insert  `\[AlignmentMarker]` before the character  you want to align on and it works: try this `Column[{"x \[AlignmentMarker]= 1+t", 
  "two \[AlignmentMarker]< 1-t^2", 
  "three \[AlignmentMarker]\[NotEqual] 1+t^3"}, 
 Alignment -> "\[AlignmentMarker]"]`

Comment: @murray as others have stated *Mathematica* isn't really a typesetting engine.  I approached this problem from the perspective of output formatting rather than typesetting, as P. Fonseca has already addressed that.

Comment: @Sjoerd C. de Vries: Aha: `\[AlignmentMarker]`! Thank you for reminding me about that.

Answer (score 17):

For convenient typesetting, I would use a palette in this case:

```
CreatePalette[
 Column[{
   "Extensible Brackets",
   Style[
    Grid[
     Join[
      Partition[
       Map[PasteButton[
          Style[RawBoxes@
            RowBox@Insert[#, "\[SelectionPlaceholder]", 2], 
           SpanMaxSize -> Infinity]] &, 
        Most@Tuples[{{"[", "{", ""}, {"]", "}", ""}}]
        ], 4],
      Map[
       PasteButton[
         RawBoxes[#]] &, {{UnderscriptBox["\[SelectionPlaceholder]", 
          "︸"], UnderscriptBox["\[SelectionPlaceholder]", "︶"], 
         UnderscriptBox["\[SelectionPlaceholder]", "\[UnderBracket]"],
          UnderscriptBox["\[SelectionPlaceholder]", "_"]},
        {OverscriptBox["\[SelectionPlaceholder]", "︷"], 
         OverscriptBox["\[SelectionPlaceholder]", "︵"], 
         OverscriptBox["\[SelectionPlaceholder]", "\[OverBracket]"], 
         OverscriptBox["\[SelectionPlaceholder]", "_"]}}, {2}]
      ]
     , Spacings -> {0, 0}], FontSize -> 8]
   }]
 ]
```

[image: palette]

All of these templates show some combination of delimiters that can be extended, either vertically or horizontally. To use the vertical unbalanced delimiters, you should normally first make sure that you're in a `TraditionalForm` environment so that the parser doesn't try to balance the brackets. This is based on my interpretation that you want to use these braces purely in typesetting and not as a function such as `Piecewise`.

As for the vertical alignment, a palette can also help with that. Have a look at the plain `Row` and `Column` templates in the `Basic Math Assistant` palette, for example.

**Usage examples**

Typesetting vertically stretched delimiters would realistically happen mostly in a `DisplayFormula` environment. This is what you see here (numbered equations):

[image: usage]

To get these forms, just press the corresponding template button in the palette and then enter the column into the black square indicating the placeholder. Alternatively, highlight an existing column and press the button to apply the delimiters.

Likewise, you can do these things in a text cell by opening an inline cell as one always does for equations, and then proceeding as above:

[image: text cell]

Comment: It looks alright in `DisplayFormula` style.  (I don't know why I didn't try that.) +1

Comment: I added a picture showing that it also works in an inline cell. Hope that clarifies it.

Comment: Side note: we can also `SetOptions[StyleBox, SpanMaxSize -> Infinity]` since _v9.0.1_. (Yeah, this doesn't even work in _v8_, maybe a bug. )

Answer (score 4):

There are probably easier ways to do this, but nothing comes to mind at the moment:

```
CellPrint@
  Cell[
   BoxData[
    FormBox[
      GridBox[
      {
       {"\[Piecewise]", 
        GridBox[
         {
          {RowBox[{"x", "\[AlignmentMarker]=", "1", "+", "t"}]},
          {RowBox[{"y", "\[AlignmentMarker]=", "1", "-", SuperscriptBox["t", "2"]}]}
          },
         GridBoxAlignment -> {"Columns" -> {{"\[AlignmentMarker]"}}},
         GridBoxSpacings -> {"Rows" -> {Offset[0.2], {Offset[0.84]}, Offset[0.2]}}]
        }
       }, 
      GridBoxSpacings -> {"Rows" -> {Offset[0.2], {Offset[0.4]}, Offset[0.2]}}], 
      TraditionalForm
     ]
    ], "Output"
  ]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that the alignment marker will become invisible once you have typed it. See also [ref:Structural Elements And Keyboard Characters](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/StructuralElementsAndKeyboardCharacters.html).

Answer (score 0):

I have used Grid and the Piecewise symbol as follows:

```
TraditionalForm@
Grid[{{"Parametric equations = ", 
    Style[TraditionalForm@"\[Piecewise]", 
    FontSize -> 36], TraditionalForm[x == 1 + t], 
    0 < t < 1}, {SpanFromAbove, 
    SpanFromAbove, TraditionalForm[y == 1 + t^2], t >= 0}}, 
    Alignment -> {{Center, Center, Left, Center}, Center}]
```

which gives the following result:

[image]

Ideally I'd improve this in the following ways:

1. Find a way to make the bracket less bold.
2. Find a way to make the Grid's Alignment option align on the = character. For some reason this does not behave as I would expect. have

Comment: That answer won't meet my needs in that it hard-codes the font size of the brace-- which means that magnifying the notebook won't work properly resize the brace.

Comment: @murray Using magnifications should change the size of everything.  Could you link an image of what you're seeing?

Comment: As an alternative, you can try the following: instead of using `FontSize -> 36` to size the brace, you can use `SpanMinSize -> 2`, which spans the brace to twice the font size. The resulting brace looks more appealing, but it may also not scale up in the way you wish. @murray

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: You're correct, that changing the magnification does change the brace's size, too, even when the `FontSize` is hard-coded. However, if I switch from Working screen environment to Presentation screen environment, the brace does not stretch to enclose the full height of the lines.