# How to convert equations to piecewise form

Tags: output-formatting

```
equations={{2 u,2,1+t,1}=={a c,a b+c,a+b,1},{u,t,0,1}=={c d,c+b d,b+d,1}};
Thread/@equations//TraditionalForm
```

equations was typed to do some `Solve`

How to get the following TraditionalForm

I typed(I hate typing directly too much) the following equations by hand to show the result expected.

Saving equations to `.tex` also could get beautiful appearance.

I'd like the equations become beautiful in *Mathematica* or *Tex*( Row/Column seems will not preserve the effect after converting to *Tex*).

So how to convert equations to (1) or (2) both in Notebook and `TeXForm`?

[image](1)

[image](2)

as @chris mentioned in the comment, this is one good look, so problem is to convert equations to `Piecewise` in this way.

```
f[x_] = Piecewise@{{Sin[x], x < 0}, {x, x >= 0 && x < 1}, {x^2, x >= 1}} 

f[x]//TeXForm
```

\begin{cases}
 \sin (x) & x<0 \\
 x & x\geq 0\land x<1 \\
 x^2 & x\geq 1
\end{cases}

Comment: Do you want spaces between symbols? Is that all, or do you see another problems?

Comment: @belisarius spaces are times, want or not both ok. In Mathematica should have spaces for a c means a*c

Comment: `f[x_] = Piecewise@{{Sin[x], x < 0},
   {x, x >= 0 && x < 1}, {x^2, x >= 1}}` would take `f[x]//TeXForm` ?

Comment: @chris yes, something like this, but `f[x]` was not created by `Piecewise` directly, but from `equations`

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be after this good discussion on [curly braces](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21082/how-stretch-curly-brace-on-multi-line-text/21144#21144).

There is also a [Piecewise](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Piecewise.html?q=Piecewise&lang=en) command, but you seem to be more interested in typesetting.

You can then use the [TeXForm](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TeXForm.html) command for conversion. Also consider using the [Export](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Export.html?q=Export&lang=en) command if you're comfortable just using an image in your other document.

Comment: The problem is how to convert the `equations` to `Piecewise` form. Not by hand (typesetting)... I hate to typeset too much.

Comment: see this https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/202719/how-to-convert-output-from-reduce-into-a-piecewise-function/212196#212196