# How to convert output from Reduce into a piecewise function?

Tags: equation-solving, function-construction, piecewise

`Reduce` often provides a much fuller solution than `Solve`. But it's always in the form of a true statement rather than functions or replacement rules, e.g.

Input:

```
Reduce[Sin[x^2] + Cos[a] == 0 && -π/2 <= x <= π/2, x]
```

Output:

```
(Cos[a] == -1 && (x == -Sqrt[(π/2)] || x == Sqrt[π/2])) ||
(-1 < Cos[a] <= Sin[1/4 (-4 π + π^2)] &&
    (x == -Sqrt[π + ArcSin[Cos[a]]] || x == Sqrt[π + ArcSin[Cos[a]]])) ||
        (Cos[a] == 0 && x == 0) ||
        (-1 < Cos[a] < 0 && (x == -Sqrt[-ArcSin[Cos[a]]] || x == Sqrt[-ArcSin[Cos[a]]]))
```

What I need is a function that takes the variable solved for (i.e. `x` here) as its input and gives corresponding value (or a list of values/separate functions for non-unique solutions) as the output. For example, the above output would be represented similarly to the following:

```
solution[x_] = Piecewise[{
    {{-Sqrt[Pi/2], Sqrt[Pi/2]}, Cos[a] == -1},
    {{-Sqrt[Pi + ArcSin[Cos[a]]], Sqrt[Pi + ArcSin[Cos[a]]]}, 
        -1 < Cos[a] <= Sin[(1/4)*(-4*Pi + Pi^2)]},
    {0, Cos[a] == 0},
    {{-Sqrt[-ArcSin[Cos[a]]], Sqrt[-ArcSin[Cos[a]]]}, 
     -1 < Cos[a] < 0}}]
```

What is a good way to transform the expression returned by `Reduce` to such a function?

Comment: Removing `In[..]` and `Out[..]` has been discussed [here](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1027/what-kind-of-input-and-output-code-styles-are-acceptable-in-se), and it was accepted as a consensus. You are welcome to add comments at the post there if you think that discussion should be restarted.

Comment: @rhermans I've changed it to a less controversial variant, where both your and my concerns are both addressed.

Answer (score 4):

Convert it to string and solve it.

```
convert[x_] := 
  x /. (Or[(a_) && (b_)]) :> {b, a} // InputForm // ToString // 
     StringReplace[#, "||" -> ","] & // "Piecewise[{" ~~ # ~~ "}]" & //
    ToExpression;
```

this works for easy situation, for example:

```
convert[(a <= -2 && 1 + 2 a <= y <= 1) || (-2 < a <= 2 (1 - Sqrt[2]) &&
     1/4 (4 a - a^2) <= y <= 1) || (2 (1 - Sqrt[2]) < a <= 
     2 (-1 + Sqrt[2]) && -1 <= y <= 1) || (2 (-1 + Sqrt[2]) < a <= 
     2 && -1 <= y <= 1/4 (4 a + a^2)) || (a > 2 && -1 <= 
     y <= -1 + 2 a)]
```

gives
$$\begin{cases}
 2 a+1\leq y\leq 1 & a\leq -2 \\
 \frac{1}{4} \left(4 a-a^2\right)\leq y\leq 1 & -2<a\leq 2 \left(1-\sqrt{2}\right) \\
 -1\leq y\leq 1 & 2 \left(1-\sqrt{2}\right)<a\leq 2 \left(\sqrt{2}-1\right) \\
 -1\leq y\leq \frac{1}{4} \left(a^2+4 a\right) & 2 \left(\sqrt{2}-1\right)<a\leq 2 \\
 -1\leq y\leq 2 a-1 & a>2
\end{cases}$$

but for complex situations,someone told me a better solution.

```
/. (Or[a_ && b_]) :> {b, a} // Apply[Piecewise[{##}] &]
```

for example

```
(Cos[a] == -1 && (x == -Sqrt[(\[Pi]/2)] || 
       x == Sqrt[\[Pi]/2])) || (-1 < Cos[a] <= 
      Sin[1/4 (-4 \[Pi] + \[Pi]^2)] && (x == -Sqrt[\[Pi] + 
           ArcSin[Cos[a]]] || 
       x == Sqrt[\[Pi] + ArcSin[Cos[a]]])) || (Cos[a] == 0 && 
     x == 0) || (-1 < Cos[a] < 
      0 && (x == -Sqrt[-ArcSin[Cos[a]]] || 
       x == Sqrt[-ArcSin[Cos[a]]])) /. (Or[a_ && b_]) :> {b, a} // 
 Apply[Piecewise[{##}] &]
```

gives

$$
\begin{cases}
x=-\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}\lor x=\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} & \cos (a)=-1 \\
 x=-\sqrt{\sin ^{-1}(\cos (a))+\pi }\lor x=\sqrt{\sin ^{-1}(\cos (a))+\pi } & -1<\cos (a)\leq \sin \left(\frac{1}{4} \left(\pi ^2-4 \pi \right)\right) \\
 x=0 & \cos (a)=0 \\
 x=-\sqrt{-\sin ^{-1}(\cos (a))}\lor x=\sqrt{-\sin ^{-1}(\cos (a))} & -1<\cos (a)<0 \\
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 3):

At least for the OP's specific case, here is one possibility:

```
Piecewise[Append[
          KeyValueMap[{#2, #1} &, 
                      GroupBy[Cases[
                      BooleanConvert[Reduce[Sin[x^2] + Cos[a] == 0 &&
                                            -π/2 <= x <= π/2, x], "DNF"],
                      x == expr_ && cond_ :> {expr, cond}, {1}], 
                      Last -> First]], {Indeterminate, True}]]
```

[image: result]

Comment: OK, so this works fine for the OP case. But can you think of a case when this would fail?

Comment: It would surely fail if `Reduce[]` encounters a function it can't invert.