# How to typeset a system of equations with multiple alignment points

Tags: formatting

I'm aware of how to align a system of equations on the = sign (or other single alignment point), but I'd like to align a system at multiple points so that each variable stays in its own "column" so to speak.  This is especially an issue if some variables have a 0 coefficient in some equations.

I'd like to extend this idea to typesetting a linear programming problem such as this:

[image]

I use \alignat in LaTeX for this, but am trying to write more in Mathematica and would like to learn how to do it there.

Thanks!

Comment: Some ideas [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21082/how-stretch-curly-brace-on-multi-line-text).

Comment: I think at some level you'll have to use [`Grid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Grid.html).  Note it can be entered in any cell directly with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>, etc.  See the link.

Comment: fyi, question is posted at community. http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/161293?p_p_auth=jAPxO1LC  please do not post in two places without pointing links to each others. Someone might end up wasting their time trying to solve something already solved or ask a question already answered at the other place.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is for typesetting equations in text cells rather than for input the way I would tackle this problem is not particularly elegant but what I would do is start with a set of equations with all terms present, e.g.

[image]

I would then edit to make some of the terms invisible

[image]

After selecting parts of your equation go to the option inspector and find `ShowContents`

[image]

Now set that to False:

[image]

The continue this process throughout the set of equations:

[image]

You could also set this up programmatically using `Invisible` to return a cell with all this in it but for typesetting in text cells I think this is the more straight forward method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example taking LaTeX code for an array (similar to `\alignat`). This example is far from a generalized way to take LaTeX skills and translate them into good typeset in *Mathematica*, but in this case it turns out to be pretty effective.

First build the LaTeX code for an array inside quotes (double up on the backslashes):

```
tex=
"\\[
 \\begin{array}{llllllllll}
  2x_1 & -3x_2 & -5x_3 & -4 x_4 & -s_1 &      &      & +a_1 & &      & =20\\\\
  7x_1 & +2x_2 & +6x_3 & -2 x_4 &      & +s_2 &      &      & &      & =35\\\\
  4x_1 & +5x_2 & -3x_3 & -2 x_4 &      &      & -s_3 &      & & +a_3 & =15\\\\
\\end{array}
\\]";
```

Then evaluate:

```
ToExpression[tex, TeXForm][[1]]
Grid[%]
```

There are two outputs, the latter being the desirable one:

[image]

A block of LaTeX code inside *Mathematica* code did not work so well in this post, and that is why I broke it into two pieces. The `Grid[ ]` function is giving the output without the undesirable matrix brackets.