# How to type text with an underbrace underneath it like: $\underbrace{g...g}_{n-times}$?

Tags: formatting, text

I want to use the underbrace "esc u{ esc" but have it placed underneath text. Like $$\underbrace{g...g}_{n-times}$$

in a mathematica text cell. Is it possible? Thanks

Comment: There's also [this palette](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21125/245) that I made for a different question.

Comment: @Jens That's really neat, thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You want to use an [`UnderBrace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/UnderBrace.html). Highlight the `g....g` then type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-4 to get under it, then type <kbd>Esc</kbd> `u{` <kbd>Esc</kbd>, then highlight the underbracket and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-4 again, gives this

[image]

To get better, you might want to use Szabolcs's [MaTeX package](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html), in which case you will get an image of the rendered TeX,

```
<<MaTeX`
MaTeX@Underscript["g...g", Underscript[︸, "n-times"]]
```

[image]

Actually just installed the package for this answer and it's my new favorite, you can simply enter TeX and have it evaluated (with the caveat that you need to use `\\` when you would use `\` in TeX),

```
MaTeX["\\underbrace{g....g}_{n-times}", FontSize -> 18]
```

[image]

And for those of you, like me, who are using the latest stable release of Ubuntu, then in order to get the required version of ghostscript you need to follow the advice from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/675710/343237) as well as having the lmodern fonts installed with `sudo apt-get install lmodern`

Answer (score 1):

Note that the keyboard shortcut for getting under an expression is now Shift + Control + ,
Thus:

- Highlight text
- Shift + Control + ,
- Esc + u { + Esc
- Highlight text AND underbracket
- Shift + Control + ,
- Type text under the underbracket