# Brackets of matrices don't size

Tags: notebooks, formatting

I have a simple question.
Switching from v9 to v10 I find that the brackets of matrices in text and input cells don't fit the size of the matrix, they are just small ordinary brackets.
There must be some global option to be changed - I can't find it.

The CellExpression for an Input-cell is the same in both versions:

```
Cell[BoxData[
 RowBox[{"(", GridBox[{
    {"1"},
    {"2"}
   }], ")"}]], "Input"]
```

I assume the reason is some burried Option.

Comment: Please add the actual Cell expression from the Notebook that exhibits this problem.  Use menu **Cell** > **Show Expression** and then copy and paste the content into your Question.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue, and have never observed it in any version of *Mathematica* on Mac OS X. Maybe your operating system info will help someone give an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most likely candidate for the "buried Option" is [`SpanMaxSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SpanMaxSize.html).  Please tell me what this looks like on your system:

```
Format[paren[obj_]] := 
 Style[DisplayForm @ RowBox[{"(", obj, ")"}], SpanMaxSize -> Infinity]

paren @ Column @ {1, 2, 3}
```

[image]

Also please try:

```
Format[paren2[obj_]] := 
 Style[DisplayForm@RowBox[{"(", obj, ")"}], SpanMaxSize -> Infinity, 
  SpanMinSize -> 10]

paren2 @ Column @ {1, 2, 3}
```

[image]

If that does not work please also try the example with `bracket` from [How stretch curly brace on multi-line text?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21082/how-stretch-curly-brace-on-multi-line-text/21121#21121)  I believe the explicit `SpanMaxSize -> Infinity` should override other possibly incorrect settings.  If this does not work I think you may have a font problem; if Mathematica cannot find the extensible glyph it may have substituted a plain parenthesis glyph.

Comment: Thank you. That was a promising answer. But it didn't work. Even your code gave as a result small typewriter like brackets unaffected by SpanMaxSize and SpanMinSize

Comment: @Darwin1871 In that case as stated I suspect a font problem.  Do any other characters like the radical symbol have similar problems?  In any case this probably needs to be handled by official Wolfram support.